# MockMVC with a @Query in my Repository or refactor my controller to not use it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, mockmvc

I have a @Query in my Repository that I return data to my controller based on a SQL Query, how would I mock this?

Here is my Repository

```
package movieweb.movies.repository;

import movieweb.movies.models.UserMovies;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface UserMoviesRepository extends CrudRepository<UserMovies, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "select * from movies, user_movies where movies.movie_id = user_movies.movie_id and uname = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<UserMovies> findByUname(String uname);
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
package movieweb.movies.controllers;

import movieweb.movies.models.Movies;
import movieweb.movies.models.UserMovies;
import movieweb.movies.repository.UserMoviesRepository;
import org.apache.catalina.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class UserMoviesController {

    @Autowired
    private UserMoviesRepository umRepository;

    @CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(path = "/newUserMovie")
    public ResponseEntity<UserMovies> addNewUserMovie(@RequestBody UserMovies data){
          umRepository.save(data);
        return new ResponseEntity<UserMovies>(data, HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(path="/getUserMovies")
    public  List<UserMovies> getUsersMovies(){
        return (List<UserMovies>) umRepository.findAll();
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping(path = "/getUserMovies/{uname}")
    public  List<UserMovies> getUserMovies(@PathVariable String uname){
        return umRepository.findByUname(uname);
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @DeleteMapping(path ="/deleteUserMovies/{id}")
    ResponseEntity deleteUserMovie(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        umRepository.deleteById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    @CrossOrigin
    @PutMapping("/usermovie/update/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserMovies> updateMovie(@RequestBody UserMovies updateMovie, @PathVariable Integer id) {
       return umRepository.findById(id)
                .map(userMovies -> {
                    userMovies.setMovieId(updateMovie.getMovieId());
                    userMovies.setUname(updateMovie.getUname());
                     umRepository.save(userMovies);
                    return new ResponseEntity<UserMovies>(userMovies, HttpStatus.OK);

                })
                .orElseGet(() -> {
                    updateMovie.setMovieId(id);
                     umRepository.save(updateMovie);
                    return new ResponseEntity<UserMovies>(updateMovie, HttpStatus.OK);
                });
    }

}
```

And here is what I am trying to do in my test

```
@Test
    void getUserMoviesPerUser() throws Exception{
        ArrayList<UserMovies> userMovies = new ArrayList<>();
        userMovies.add(new UserMovies(1, "jamie", 1));
        userMovies.add(new UserMovies(2, "joe", 1));
        userMovies.add(new UserMovies(3, "jamie", 2));
        userMovies.add(new UserMovies(4, "joe", 2));

        when(userMoviesRepository.findByUname("jamie")).thenReturn(userMovies);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/getUserMovies/{uname}", "jamie"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].userMovieID", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].uname", is("jamie")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].movieId", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].userMovieID", is(3)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].uname", is("jamie")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].movieId", is(1)));

        Mockito.verify(userMoviesRepository, times(1)).findAll();
    }
```

The problem I am facing is when I run the test above I am not getting back just 2 records like I would expect, I get back 4. This makes sense in the fact that I cant depend on SQL to run tests. Is there a better way to write my controller to get the data based on movie_id?

Comment: sorry i don't understand your question clearly, make sure your mocks are correct

Comment: My question is how would I write this so that the mock reflects what should be going on when I pass the movie_id to the SQL Query where it only returns items that have a specific movie_id foreign key?

Comment: then you should probably think for in memory database like `H2`

Comment: I have a AWS RDS I am using, the issue I'm trying to solve here is how to make my mock work.

Comment: Note that you almost certainly don't need that custom query; Spring Data can construct most queries for you. Additionally, you're adding redundant information in your paths; just `POST /usermovies` for new, and `GET|PUT|DELETE /usermovies/{id}`.

Comment: @chrylis -on strike can you recommend a good resource to learn how to get Spring Data to let me get a query by column name?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are creating `4 records` for mocking then simply remove `2 of them` so that you have `2 records` as response.

```
@Test
void getUserMoviesPerUser() throws Exception{
    ArrayList<UserMovies> userMovies = new ArrayList<>();
    userMovies.add(new UserMovies(1, "jamie", 1));
    userMovies.add(new UserMovies(2, "joe", 1));

    when(userMoviesRepository.findByUname("jamie")).thenReturn(userMovies);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/getUserMovies/{uname}", "jamie"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].userMovieID", is(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].uname", is("jamie")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].movieId", is(1)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].userMovieID", is(3)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].uname", is("jamie")))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].movieId", is(1)));

    Mockito.verify(userMoviesRepository, times(1)).findAll();
}
```

Comment: So how would that mock test the findbyusername that uses the SQL statement or does the test not care it just wants the results?

Comment: If you want to test `SQL or JPA repositories` that I think you want to do, you can use `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` + `@DataJpaTest` then `@Autowired TestEntityManager entityManager;` you can achievement what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return the only records you were expecting. like

```
@Test
    void getUserMoviesPerUser() throws Exception{
        ArrayList<UserMovies> userMovies = new ArrayList<>();
        userMovies.add(new UserMovies(1, "jamie", 1));
        userMovies.add(new UserMovies(3, "jamie", 2));

        when(userMoviesRepository.findByUname("jamie")).thenReturn(userMovies);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/getUserMovies/{uname}", "jamie"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].userMovieID", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].uname", is("jamie")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].movieId", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].userMovieID", is(3)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].uname", is("jamie")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].movieId", is(1)));

        Mockito.verify(userMoviesRepository, times(1)).findAll();
    }
```

Comment: So how would that mock test the findbyusername that uses the SQL statement or does the test not care it just wants the results?

Comment: Mock will not call the SQL statement.
Here we are passing the result after the execution of your userMoviesRepository.findByUname
using when and then. We are not actually calling your databse